# PDF shows only 1 page, in every browser using iOS devices

Tags: php, html

Has anyone encountered wherein pdf files only shows 1 page when using iOS device, like every browser in iOS.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="files/Images/logoapp.png">
    <title></title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
   --PHP CODE--
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php 
        $fileLink = $_GET['viewresearch'];
    ?>
    <embed
    src="admin/files/RepositoryFiles/<?php echo $fileLink; ?>"
    type="application/pdf"
    frameBorder="0"
    scrolling="auto"
    height="100%"
    width="100%"
>
```

this code is working on every mobile phone that I used, however it won't do its job when using iOS devices. I am using localhost right now to interact with my project. Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the scrolling auto and height...

Comment: @KevinGales I have tried your solution, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with safari browser other than that it works fine on other browsers in ios...so why not check if is safari then do this (preview<a href="yourpdf.pdf">Read pdf here</a>

Comment: @KevinGales you mean I'll let the user click the <a> tag? but I'm already fetching the data using the $_GET.

Comment: Add this after the embed <a href="admin/files/RepositoryFiles/<?=$fileLink; ?>">[styled button]Read full</a> in capable browsers you won't see the <a>Read full tag but in safari you will